# Play in scale like Ableton's Push controller using a drum rack/other?

Tags: ableton

Ableton's new Push controller allows one to play only in certain scales, is this something that can be mimic'ed in a drum rack or something else? Are there any VSTs that have this ability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Live has a "Scale" MIDI device that filters incoming notes and snaps them to the closest "correct" scale note. You can find it under MIDI Effects in the browser.

[image: image from hearandknow.wordpress.com/2013/01/01/generating-drum-fills/, found on GIS]

This won't be as useful in a drum rack, where the contents of individual cells don't necessarily have any association with the note that triggers them, but for any tonal instrument it should work just fine.